# accordion edit wordpress

Tags: wordpress, accordion

I am developing a WP website

i have used accordions in the page .Have used Image menu widget plugin

The  looks like as follows:

[image]

I want to remove the triangle in accordions.

Can anyone tell me about same?

**edit1**

in this it shows the triangle element
but is it possible to directly delete it from there...?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They'll be in the CSS, you'll need to provide a link to get a definitive answer from somebody on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in case you are not able to find out the css , You can hide the content for this class.

```
<span class="triangle"></span>

span.triangle
{
display:none;
}
```

triangle is the class which is associate with the span at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `ul` `li` element attributes in your `css`, use `firebug` for that or provide some css/link for more clarification

Comment: @pradnya im not sure as styling is not very visible but chk background-image or provide the style sheet...ues FIREBUG addon